# Spring Reactor Retry.retryWhen() did not work

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

how to use retry?
i want to retry to call method when error until it`s successed.
**my test code**

```java
@Test
    public void fun1() throws InterruptedException {
        this.generate()
                .retryWhen(Retry.fixedDelay(5, Duration.ofMillis(1))
                        .filter(e -> e instanceof Exception)
                        .doBeforeRetry(res -> System.out.println("retry begin"))
                        .doAfterRetry(res -> System.out.println("try finished")))
                .onErrorContinue((throwable, o) -> System.out.println(throwable))
                .subscribe(System.out::println);
    }

    private Mono<String> generate() throws InterruptedException {
        if (retryTime.get() == 3) {
            return Mono.just("Hello");
        }
        System.out.println("i am called" + retryTime.getAndAdd(1));
        return Mono.error(new IllegalArgumentException("exception test"));
    }
```

** but get this result**

```
i am called1
10:02:12.104 [main] DEBUG reactor.util.Loggers - Using Slf4j logging framework
retry begin
try finished
retry begin
try finished
retry begin
try finished
retry begin
try finished
retry begin
try finished
reactor.core.Exceptions$RetryExhaustedException: Retries exhausted: 5/5

Process finished with exit code 0
```

why not retry three times until success???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Retry works by *re-subscribing* to the result of the upstream methods.  It does not *re-invoke* the upstream methods.

In your case specifically, each subscription from `.retryWhen` is subscribing to the `Mono.error` returned from the single call to `generate()`.  Therefore, each subscription sees the same exception result.

To fix this, you need to defer the logic inside the `generate()` method to occur at *subscription* time, rather than *assembly* time.

For example, use `Mono.fromCallable`, like this:

```java
    private Mono<String> generate() {
        return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
            if (retryTime.get() == 3) {
                return "Hello";
            }
            System.out.println("i am called" + retryTime.getAndAdd(1));
            throw new new IllegalArgumentException("exception test");
        });
    }
```

The Callable will be called for each subscriber.  Specifically, it will be called each time the `retryWhen` operator re-subscribes.